# Exception on executing ext:news upgrade wizard for updating path_segment in TYPO3 9

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-9.x

After upgrading to TYPO3 9, some of the tx_news_domain_model_news path_segment fields were empty, so I marked **Upgrade Wizard** 
*"Updates slug field "path_segment" of EXT:news records" of news extension"* as undone and tried to execute it. This throws an **exception**. Makes no difference if executed via backend or on command line, though the command line shows a success message before the error::

```
typo3-cli upgrade:run newsSlug
```

Output:

```
In UpgradeWizardsService.php line 466:

No valid wizard identifier given  


in /var/www/domain/htdocs/typo3_src-9.5.5/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Service/UpgradeWizardsService.php line 466
     */
    protected function assertIdentifierIsValid(string $identifier): void
    {
        if ($identifier === '' || (!isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ext/install']['update'][$identifier]) && !is_subclass_of($identifier, RowUpdaterInterface::class))) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('No valid wizard identifier given', 1502721731);
        }
    }
}
```

Current TYPO3 version 9.5.5.

There are changelog entries:

- [Deprecation: #86366 - Methods in AbstractUpdate](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.5/Deprecation-86366-MethodsInAbstractUpdate.html)
- [Feature: #86076 - New API for UpgradeWizards](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/9.4/Feature-86076-NewAPIForUpgradeWizards.html)

There is a new Interface for upgrade wizard, but as far as I understand it, the "old" update wizards with AbstractUpdate should still work in 9.x.

---

Is this a bug? I've got the original problem solved, because the update wizard did successfully convert the entries (see [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948296/2444812)).

I'd just like to have clarification for implementation of update wizards in TYPO3 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this was a bug in the news extension and fixed in master. Be aware that the implementation of update wizards changed in 9 a bit, therefore also this bug occurred.